# Money in a piggy bank

Tags: calculation-puzzle

In the attic of his house a man found an old piggy bank with twelve cents inside. He called two of his friends to come and see the antique piggy bank and asked them to put more money into the piggy bank. The first friend put 700% of the original amount and the second friend put 1175%. The man who found the piggy bank also added money to the piggy bank. Afterwards, they counted the money. The piggy bank now contained a total of $7.20. What percentage was the last deposit into the piggy bank?

Comment: Failing to see a trick here, seems like just a simple maths problem to me?

Comment: Percentages depend on what the base is.  Is the 1175% taken on the original 12 cents, or on what was there after the first friend's deposit?  Is the last deposit taken as a percentage of 12 cents or the current contents of the bank?  Once those are answered, it is a calculation.

Comment: 1175% of the original 12 cents. The last deposit is also a percentage of  the original 12 cents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everything is a percentage of the original 12 cents, this is a simple calculation :
(Every percentage is expressed as a fraction here, as this is easier to combine)

> `720 = 12 + 12*7 + 12*11.75 + 12*X`, where X is the last percentage added

> =>  `720/12 = 1 + 7 + 11.75 + X`
>
>   => `60 = 19.75 + X`
>
>   => `X = 60 - 19.75 = 40.25`

> So the last percentage is 4025%